# Writing an XLSX file with image data in a cell

Tags: javascript, html-table, xlsx

I have a HTML Table containing an [img src="data:image/png;base64,[image data]" /] in one of the cells. I would like to take this HTML Table and write an XLSX file using Javascript which will contain the image data for the cell.

I have tried using http://sheetjs.com, but the image data is lost.

What is the best solution (if there is one) for this problem?